# physical model data types

Tags: database, physical-design

I'm trying to convert a logical model to a physical model and I saw an example here http://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/data-modeling-levels.html which doesn't have `null` or `not null`. Next to the data types, does `null` or `not null`  need to be in a physical model ?...Also I see a lot `VARCHAR2(30)` in the models, I know it depends on a situation of course but when would you have `VARCHAR2(50)` ? would you want it when you have a column something like description, location or street address ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you need null or not null next to data types in a physical model ? or is that optional ?

Comment: Depends on your notation method. Ultimately you must specify it in the ddl or the database engine chooses.